# Validate Camel route programmatically

Tags: apache-camel

I'm working on a logging solution where Camel routes are defined at runtime with a Java DSL String. I wonder if there's a way to check programmatically some errors such as components not found in the route. The only option I was able to find is catching the `org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException` and dig into the error message. Is there a better way to validate the route?

Just to give an example, it would be good to ascertain if a route syntax is completely wrong or if just a component wasn't found so that I can output a message e.g. "install ftp component".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **Fabric8 Camel Maven Plugin** (http://fabric8.io/guide/camelMavenPlugin.html) for validating Camel endpoints in the source code.

Look at this article by Claus Ibsen to get more information : https://blog.fabric8.io/cheers-fabric8-camel-maven-plugin-to-validate-camel-endpoints-from-source-code-8768aff76b41#.wcji8hfdg

Comment: Yes and that maven plugin will come out of the box from Camel 2.19 onwards. And if you use IDEA editor there is a plugin that can validate your source code as you type: https://github.com/davsclaus/camel-idea-plugin

Comment: I have an application where in we add routes to camel context at run time (route is built based on configurations). Can we use this plugin to validate the route XML before adding it to the context ?. (the problem I'm running into is : if a malformed route XML is being added to an active context, it is bringing down the entire context)

Comment: I solved the problem by having a dummy camel context on my application. Before adding it to main context, I add the route XML to dummy context and try to start the context, if it starts successfully then I remove the XML and get it added to the actual context....it is dirty way but worked :) @ClausIbsen